# How does the form_for method know which controller#action to send the resulting hash to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I assume there are some sort of conventions involved. What are they?

Assuming the `@person` is a resource instance with correct entries, where would the data from this form go?

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  First name: <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
  Last name : <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />
  Biography : <%= f.text_area :biography %><br />
  Admin?    : <%= f.check_box :admin %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it's a convention. Rails will look if the `@person` is an existing record or a new one (it depends on whether `@person.id` existis).

- If `@person` is a `new record`, Rails will point the action of the form to `PeopleController.create` action with a `POST` request
- If `@person` is an `existing record`, Rails will point the action of the form to `PeopleController.update` action with the @person.id as a parameter (which will come in params[:id]) and make a `PATCH` request